# PE file structure

Tags: file, winapi, dll, executable, portable-executable

Hopefully someone can answer these questions for me, thank you.

- Looking at msdn and other documentation, I see that the data descriptions of a PE file contain an RVA to the imports table section (.idata). However, the sections table also contains an RVA to the idata section, isn't this redundant?
- Secondly, I have read about the import lookup/name table, the import address table, the import directory table and the hint/name table, and I wonder why the ILT does not contain the name of the function, but instead contains an RVA to the hint/name table? Or in other words, why does the import directory table not refer to the hint/name table directly, but uses the ILT as a wrapper (is it because in the ILT it is defined if it is called with an ordinal/by its name?
- As far as I know, the IAT can also be read-only, but in that case is it still part of the .idata section or the .rdata section (I read that the section names are not that important, it can be changed without serious consequences).

Thank you for all of your help!

Comment: _"I see that the data descriptions of a PE file contain an RVA to the imports table section (.idata). However, the sections table also contains an RVA to the idata section, isn't this redundant?"_ - what "data descriptions" are you referring to, exactly? I'm looking at [the PE/COFF specification](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/debug/pe-format) right now and the only `.idata` address is in the Data Directories table, but the `.idata` address is that of the imports-table, not the import-section - perhaps that's what's throwing you off?

Comment: Hi Dai, Thank you for your reaction. Maybe that´s wat confusing me indeed, but when I look at the specification it mentions that the data descriptions of the optional header refer to the import table, which consists of the IDT, ILT etc. But in that case.. what is the import section? I mean I would think that the import table = the import section, but probably I'm wrong?

Comment: Sections describe *where* memory is allocated. Directories describe how to interpret the memory. There is no rule that requires that the import-related information be put in its own section, but it is commonly done for various reasons, some practical and some traditional. "Why does the Prime Minister get the seat at the head of the table with a placard that says 'Prime Minister'? Isn't that redundant?" Well, the Prime Minister does sit at the head of the table by convention and tradition, but they could decide to sit somewhere else, and the placard tells you where the Prime Minister is.

Answer (score 0):

According to the recommendations of the community:

Refer to the Doc: [PE Format](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/debug/pe-format#the-idata-section)

.idata address is in the Data Directories table, but the .idata address is that of the imports-table

Sections describe where memory is allocated. Directories describe how to interpret the memory. There is no rule that requires that the import-related information be put in its own section, but it is commonly done for various reasons, some practical and some traditional.